# Add order numbers to children elements, 1,2,3,4,5

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm trying to output order numbers to elements that are generated from gallery captions.

```
foreach ( $item['gallery'] as $image ) {
  $lines = intval( apply_filters( 'caption_line', 1 ) );
  for ( $line = 1; $line <= $lines; $line++ ) {
    $attachment_post = get_post( $image['id'] );
    $image_caption = $attachment_post->post_excerpt;
    echo '<span class="dot1" onclick="currentSlide' . $item['unit_link'] . '(' . esc_attr( $line ) . ')">' . $image_caption . '</span>';
    }
}
```

So I need 1,2,3,4...to be generated for $line, but for what I have tried it only output 1 for all elements, changing 1  $lines = intval( apply_filters( 'caption_line', 1 ) ); to higher number shows the number, but also duplicate them.

Comment: It this wordpress?

Comment: Yup, it's a custom widget for wordpress elementor, the widget itself works fine, just need to add this number automatically based on the number of elements generated from the gallery caption array. @FarzadRastgarSani

Comment: What does the `caption_line` filter actually do? And what do you even want to do here in the first place, the description is not really that understandable to begin with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured it out, this does exactly what I was looking for!

```
foreach ( $item['gallery'] as $key => $image ) {
  $attachment_post = get_post( $image['id'] );
  $image_caption = $attachment_post->post_excerpt;
  $keyplus = $key+1;
     echo '<span class="dot1" onclick="currentSlide' . $item['unit_link'] . '(' .  $keyplus . ')">' . $image_caption . '</span>';
}
```